# SQL Query is creating way too many repeated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join

i have an issue with a sql query and how the output is being displayed, you see, i have 3 tables and have at least one field in common, the thing is when i join 2 tables together the information i need is displayed properly, but when i join the third the output goes insane and duplicates the results way too much and i need to figure out why it is happening, down below i'll show you all the tables and relations between each other

this is how the tables are related to each other

[image: l]

This is how the first table (dbo_predios) is made the first three fields are the only relevant in this case
[image]

This is how the second table (dbo_permisos_obras_mayores) is made the first three fields are the only relevant in this case as well, the second two can match the first table (dbo_predios)
[image]

And here is how the third table (dbo_recepciones_obras_mayores) is made, the fourth field is the only relevant in this case, it could relate to the second table (dbo_permisos_obras_mayores) to the same name field

[image]

okay, now that is structurewise, now the query i'm executing is the following:

```
SELECT
dbo_predios.codigo_unico_predio,
dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.numero_permiso_edificacion,
dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.fecha_permiso_edificacion
FROM dbo_predios
INNER JOIN  dbo_permisos_obras_mayores ON dbo_predios.codigo_manzana_predio = dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.codigo_manzana_predio AND dbo_predios.codigo_lote_predio = dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.codigo_lote_predio
INNER JOIN  dbo_recepciones_obras_mayores ON dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.numero_recepcion_permiso = dbo_recepciones_obras_mayores.numero_recepcion_permiso
WHERE       dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.codigo_manzana_predio = 9402 AND dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.codigo_lote_predio = 30
```

And the result of executing the query in that way is this:

[image]

Later on i did some trial and error and removed the second inner join line, and the result surprised me, here is what happened:

[image]

Conclusion: in brief the third table is causing the cartesian product, why? i wish i knew why, what do you think of this particular case? i'd thank any help you could give me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, and you'll get better help, faster. ([mcve])

Comment: I highly recommend giving your tables (which have very long names) alias in the `FROM`, and then using those in your references to columns; it'll make it much more readable. (Also, why do you tables have a prefix on `dbo_` when they are also on the `dbo` schema?)

Comment: Why do you use for PK a numeric field? In two tables.

Comment: hi @Larnu that is the way they're written here, i can't do anything about it, we'd have to rename around 500 tables or maybe more, i guess it was meant to be easy to read or identify, i know it's redundant, but it's the way the database is made

Comment: Hi @cdrrr as i said in a previous comment, maybe is not the best way to go, but where i'm working the entire database has numeric PK so i did the same for beter relation between tables

Comment: You aren't doing any cartesian products in your queries. You either have multiple `numero_recepcion_permiso` matching to the `permisos_obras_mayores` table or you are missing another link between the 2 last tables. include in your query the `numero_recepcion_permiso` and verify what's going on.

Comment: @Larnu i almost forgot, maybe momentarily i could use an alias for better reading, but i'm not allowed to do that either, i tried last time but the standard here is table.field because my workmate gets dizzy trying to read it that way and the result of that are insane queries

Comment: Your work mate get's "dizzy" reading succinct code? Most people find the opposite; and get "dizzy" from reading code that is very difficult to read (like we have here due to the huge object names that keep appearing).

Comment: Looks A LOT like Powerbuilder to me

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS It doesn't matter what your actual table & columns & alias use are, give minimal & clear example & code with the problem.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution - since you are saying that the numero_recepcion_permiso is blank, just add the condition to the inner join, to exclude empty ones:

```
SELECT
dbo_predios.codigo_unico_predio,
dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.numero_permiso_edificacion,
dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.fecha_permiso_edificacion
FROM dbo_predios
INNER JOIN  dbo_permisos_obras_mayores ON dbo_predios.codigo_manzana_predio = dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.codigo_manzana_predio AND dbo_predios.codigo_lote_predio = dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.codigo_lote_predio
INNER JOIN  dbo_recepciones_obras_mayores ON dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.numero_recepcion_permiso = dbo_recepciones_obras_mayores.numero_recepcion_permiso 
            AND dbo_recepciones_obras_mayores.numero_recepcion_permiso <>''
WHERE       dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.codigo_manzana_predio = 9402 AND dbo_permisos_obras_mayores.codigo_lote_predio = 30
```

With that said, should that field allowed to be blank or `NULL`?  Perhaps you need to add a constraint to your table to prevent that scenario. Another suggestion - why did you choose `NUMERIC(18,0)` as the data type on the primary key for those tables? I would prefer a simple `INT` or `BIGINT` and maybe let the database generate the sequence for me.

Comment: hi @Icarus and thanks for your query, and works good, but i also need the same query without the where in some cases, and gets the data very repeated, is there any way to do that the way i pose it?

Comment: @сꝛıϻѕοɴᴠᴇɴoϻ I am not sure I am following what you mean by `without the where` (?). I did not add the `AND` condition to the `where` clause; I added it to the `INNER JOIN` and therefore you should be able to eliminate the `WHERE` clause and the JOIN will still work fine except that this time, for ALL *predios* and not just a specific one. But I am sure I am misunderstanding your problem... :/

Comment: finally it worked, i made some minimal adjustments and it's all working good, thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i did what Icarus told me and i figured out something that is useful, you see, i made a big mistake and the number combination i was trying out didn't have a `numero_recepcion_permiso` so the output column is completely blank, however when there is an actual `numero_recepcion_permiso` it shows correctly, anyway i still need that doesn't output that much amount of repeated rows, how can i fix that? thank y'all for your help so far

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that both values exist in both fields and they actually match or else could generate that amount of repeated rows, however the amount of rows repeated is something i can't tell since i don't know what your actual data is, but that may clear up a Little bit that issue